# Unordered map of vectors c++

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

I´m trying for several hours now to get this right. What i want to do is have a map of vectors (the vectors contain pointers to objects) stored in an unnamed namespace. Classes are then allowed to access the data in the vector via a function call.

```
//DataHandler.cpp

#include "DataHandler.h"

using std::vector;
using std::unordered_map;

namespace DataHandler
{
  namespace
  {
    unordered_map< unsigned int, vector<MyClass*> > data_map_;
  }

  void receiveData(unsigned int key, vector< MyClass*>& data_vec)
  {
    //check if key already exists:
    unordered_map<unsigned int, vector<MyClass*> >::iterator it;

    it = data_map_.find(key);
    if (it != data_map_.end())
    {
      data_vec = it->second;
      return;
    }

    //generate new key with new data
    data_map_.insert(make_pair(key, vector< MyClass*>()));

    data_map_[key].push_back(new MyClass(/*some constructor arguments*/));
    // ... push back some more instances of MyClass ...

    //finally:
    data_vec = data_map_[key];
    return;
  }
}
```

In some other class I do this for getting the vector:

```
//SomeOtherClass.cpp

#include "SomeOtherClass.h"
#include "DataHandler.h"

using std::vector;

void SomeOtherClass::aMethod()
{
  vector<MyClass*> first;
  vector<MyClass*> second;
  vector<MyClass*> first_again;

  DataHandler::receiveData(1, first); //works fine
  DataHandler::receiveData(2, second); //works fine
  DataHandler::receiveData(1, first_again); // <- strange behavior or segfault here
}
```

So everything works as expected, besides if I want to access a vector which had previously been filled with MyClass instances - then I get strange behavior or a segmentation fault. 
Can someone explain to me why this is so and how this is done right?

Thanks!!

Comment: And how are you exactly accessing a vector which had previously been filled with `MyClass` instances ??

Comment: I'd suspect problems with dangling `MyClass` pointers or so. Use smart pointers to store the `MyClass` references in vectors, either `std::vector<std::uinque_ptr<MyClass>>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>`.

Comment: In this case, the vector is stored in the map, so i search for the key with it = data_map_.find(key) as shown in the first 9 lines in the function void receiveData(unsigned int key, vector< MyClass*>& data_vec). Consequently, the iterator points to the vector...

Comment: I´m a complete idiot. I overlooked that I deleted the MyClass instances in the vector in another place *facepalm*. 
(I can't answer my own question in less than 8 hours due to lack of reputation, so I post a comment)

Thanks guys anyways ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any specific problem, so this isn't an answer but is too long for a comment.  I'll mark it community wiki.  Anyway, why not have a `std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::vector<MyClass>>` and get rid of all the pointers and lifetime issues?  `SomeOtherClass::aMethod()` can do an `insert`, which returns an `std::pair<iterator,bool>` - just save that iterator if you want access to the `MyClass` elements later in `aMethod`.  As is, if you have some pointers in `first_again`, they're clobbered inside `receiveData()` with whatever pointers are in `first`: there are lots of ways that could be a memory leak, but I can't say for sure without seeing more of your code.